# Catch all clicks that are not in set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation drop down that displays on click. However, the pure css functionality requires you to click the link again to close the sub-menu.

I would like to modify it so that any click that is not within the sub-menu closes it.

I've tried something like this, but to no avail:

```
$('*:not(.submenu > li > a)').click(function() {
    $('nav .dropdown input').removeAttr('checked');
    console.log('clicked outside sub-menu');
});
```

This registers every click, even those that match `.submenu > li > a` meaning that the `$('nav .dropdown input').removeAttr('checked');` line does work to hide the menu, but it is called even when trying to open the menu, resulting in the menu never opening.

The CSS drop down works via a checkbox input. Here is that CSS if it helps at all, however my problem is in the Javascript, because the CSS functions just fine.

Here is a fiddle, and the CSS is below: https://jsfiddle.net/z3yj7pLs/

```
ul.dropdown {
    position:fixed;
    top:30px;
    width:100%;
    height:3em;
    margin:0;
    padding:0 10px;
    color:#eee;
}

ul.dropdown > li{
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
    position:relative;
}

ul.dropdown label{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    transition:background 0.3s;
    cursor:pointer;

    bottom: -2px;
    left: -10px;
}

ul.dropdown label:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    top:50%;
    right:5px;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-top:4px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    border-bottom:0 solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    border-left:4px solid transparent;
    border-right:4px solid transparent;
    transition:border-bottom .1s, border-top .1s .1s;
}

ul.dropdown label:hover,
ul.dropdown input:checked ~ label{

}

ul.dropdown input:checked ~ label:after{
    border-top:0 solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    border-bottom:4px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    transition:border-top .1s, border-bottom .1s .1s;
}

/*hide the inputs*/
ul.dropdown input{display:none}

/*show the second levele menu of the selected voice*/
ul.dropdown input:checked ~ ul.submenu{
    max-height:300px;
    transition:max-height 0.5s ease-in;
}

/*style for the second level menu*/
ul.dropdown ul.submenu{
    max-height:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    list-style-type:none;
    background:#444;
    box-shadow:0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    transition:max-height 0.5s ease-out;
    position:absolute;
    min-width:100%;
}

ul.dropdown ul.submenu li a{
    display:block;
    padding:12px;
    color:#ddd;
    text-decoration:none;
    box-shadow:0 -1px rgba(0,0,0,.5) inset;
    transition:background .3s;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

ul.dropdown ul.submenu li a:hover{
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If can listen to clicks on `document` and then check if the click was not inside the `dropdown`

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    if ($(event.toElement).parents('.dropdown').length > 0) {
        console.log('Clicked inside the dropdown area');
    } else {
        console.log('Clicked outside the dropdown area');
    }
});
```

Here is a working snippet:

```js
$(document).click(function(event) {
    if ($(event.toElement).parents('.dropdown').length > 0) {
      console.log('Clicked inside the dropdown area');
    } else {
        console.log('Clicked outside the dropdown area');
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
ul.dropdown {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #eee;
}

ul.dropdown > li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}

ul.dropdown label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  transition: background 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: -10px;
}

ul.dropdown label:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 50%;
  right: 5px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 4px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  border-bottom: 0 solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  transition: border-bottom .1s, border-top .1s .1s;
}

ul.dropdown label:hover,
ul.dropdown input:checked ~ label {}

ul.dropdown input:checked ~ label:after {
  border-top: 0 solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  border-bottom: 4px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  transition: border-top .1s, border-bottom .1s .1s;
}


/*hide the inputs*/

ul.dropdown input {
  display: none
}


/*show the second levele menu of the selected voice*/

ul.dropdown input:checked ~ ul.submenu {
  max-height: 300px;
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in;
}


/*style for the second level menu*/

ul.dropdown ul.submenu {
  max-height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #444;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease-out;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 100%;
}

ul.dropdown ul.submenu li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px;
  color: #ddd;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) inset;
  transition: background .3s;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

ul.dropdown ul.submenu li a:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown">
  <li>
    <input id="nav-dropdown-check" type="checkbox" name="menu" />
    <label for="nav-dropdown-check"><a class="nav-imitation">More</a></label>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">Sotto menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sotto menu 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Works great, I will remember event.toElement for the future, that's what I was looking for! Thanks!!

Comment: You are welcome :) a voteup on the answer will also be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use event delegation for this task:

```
$('body').on('click', ':not(.submenu > li > a)', function() {
    $('nav .dropdown input').removeAttr('checked');
    console.log('clicked outside sub-menu');
});
```

That way you aren't adding tons of event handlers to the DOM - just one that ignores clicks to your menu - you may need to adjust the ':not()' selector a bit or use JS in the event handler (e.g. `if (!$(this).parents('.submenu').length) { ...collapse }`

Comment: Not sure why, but this did not work in my case. Did you try a fiddle?